# How can you tell if an XMLlist object in AS3 contains a node?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, xmllist

How can you tell if an **XMLlist** object in AS3 contains a  specific node?
For ex: you have this XML file

`<items>
   <item>one</items>
           </items>`

And want to check if in this file exists a child with tag `<pp>`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var xml:XML = <items>  <item>one</items>  </items>;

// my favorite method (works also for testing attributes)

if (xml.pp.length()) {
   // xml contains one or more <pp> child elements
}
else {
   // xml contains no <pp> child elements
}
```

Answer (score 1):

used this simple code which worked:

if ("pp" in **XMLlist**) {

trace("exist");

}